# How to draw new circle on touch and remove previous circle

Tags: java, android

I can create circle on touch but can not remove the previous one. I have manage to remove the very first circle but the code is poor and it does not really work as I want. I like to draw circle every time I touch the screen and remove the previous circle . So the screen starts with a circle and as I will touch a new position the previous should be removed and there will be a new one.So how to do that part?
Here is my work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    Display display = new Display(this);
    display.init();
    display.backPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(display);
}

static class Display extends View {
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList();
    int touch1_x=700;
    int touch1_y=700;
    Paint backPaint;
    Paint circlePaint;
    Paint circlePaint2;

    Display(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    void init() {
        backPaint = new Paint();
        backPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        backPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        circlePaint2 = new Paint();
        circlePaint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getActionMasked()) {
                   // if (event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > 100 && event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) < 200) {
                        touch1_x = (int) event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
                        touch1_y = (int) event.getY(event.getActionIndex());
                   // }
                    System.out.println("touch1_x ===" + touch1_x);
                    points.add(new Point(touch1_x, touch1_y));
                    points.add(new Point(touch1_x, touch1_y));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), backPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(touch1_x, touch1_y, 50, circlePaint);

        for(Point p: points){
            canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 50, circlePaint);

        }
        for(Point p: points){
            canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 50,circlePaint2 );
        }
    invalidate();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956838/how-to-erase-previous-drawing-on-canvas)

You could erase canvas before drawing the next circle, using

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,Mode.CLEAR);
```

Comment: I believe that will erase the whole canvas. The code i put is a part of long code. I can not remove everything from canvas. Anything else?

Comment: You could have a separate canvas just for these circles, then erasing it won't affect other objects?

Or, if you only have a few other objects on your canvas in question, then you may have to redraw everything before drawing the new circle?

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()
wn=turtle.Screen()

for count in range(360):
    t.fd(3)
    t.rt(1)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a customised view for photo annotate, you can use this to do your job.

1: Create a file AnnotationView.java and copy the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * @author Bob Gao
 * http://bobgao.net
 */
public class AnnotationView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final float KEY_STROKE_WIDTH = 4;

    private List<Annotation> annotations = new ArrayList<Annotation>();
    private Annotation mAnnotation;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // private Rect mOutRect;

    public AnnotationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.mCanvas = canvas;
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            mPaint.setColor(annotation.getColor());
            switch (annotation.getShape()) {
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_CIRCLE:
                drawCircle(annotation.getX(), annotation.getY(), annotation.getRadius());
                break;
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_ARROW:
                drawAL((int) annotation.getX(), (int) annotation.getY(), (int) annotation.getRadius(), annotation.getDegree());
                break;
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_SQUARES:
                drawRect((int) annotation.getX(), (int) annotation.getY(), (int) annotation.getRadius());
                break;
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_TRIANGLE:
                drawTriangle((int) annotation.getX(), (int) annotation.getY(), (int) annotation.getRadius(), annotation.getDegree());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draw a triangle
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param r
     */
    public void drawTriangle(int x, int y, int r, float degree) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        path.lineTo(x - 2 * r, y + 2 * r);
        path.lineTo(x + 2 * r, y + 2 * r);
        path.lineTo(x, y);
        path.close();
        rotatePath(path, degree);
        mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }

    public void drawRect(int x, int y, int r) {
        int lenght = 4 * r;
        int left = x - lenght / 2;
        int top = y - lenght / 2;
        int right = x + lenght / 2;
        int bottom = y + lenght / 2;

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(left, top);
        path.lineTo(right, top);
        path.lineTo(right, bottom);
        path.lineTo(left, bottom);
        path.lineTo(left, top);
        path.close();
        mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }

    public void drawCircle(float x, float y, float r) {
        mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    }

    /**
     * Draw arrow
     * 
     * @param sx
     * @param sy
     * @param ex
     * @param ey
     */
    public void drawAL(int sx, int sy, int r, float degree) {
        int ex = (int) (sx + 2 * r);
        int ey = (int) (sy + 2 * r);
        switch (new Float(degree).intValue()) {
        case 90:
            ex = (int) (sx - 2 * r);
            ey = (int) (sy + 2 * r);
            break;
        case 180:
            ex = (int) (sx - 2 * r);
            ey = (int) (sy - 2 * r);
            break;
        case 270:
            ex = (int) (sx + 2 * r);
            ey = (int) (sy - 2 * r);
            break;
        }
        double H = 8; // the height of arrow
        double L = 3.5; // half of bottom line
        int x3 = 0;
        int y3 = 0;
        int x4 = 0;
        int y4 = 0;
        double awrad = Math.atan(L / H); // the rotation of arrow
        double arraow_len = Math.sqrt(L * L + H * H); // the length of arrow
        double[] arrXY_1 = rotateVec(ex - sx, ey - sy, awrad, true, arraow_len);
        double[] arrXY_2 = rotateVec(ex - sx, ey - sy, -awrad, true, arraow_len);
        double x_3 = ex - arrXY_1[0]; // (x3,y3) the first point
        double y_3 = ey - arrXY_1[1];
        double x_4 = ex - arrXY_2[0]; // (x4,y4) the second point
        double y_4 = ey - arrXY_2[1];
        Double X3 = new Double(x_3);
        x3 = X3.intValue();
        Double Y3 = new Double(y_3);
        y3 = Y3.intValue();
        Double X4 = new Double(x_4);
        x4 = X4.intValue();
        Double Y4 = new Double(y_4);
        y4 = Y4.intValue();
        // draw line
        mCanvas.drawLine(sx, sy, ex, ey, mPaint);
        Path triangle = new Path();
        triangle.moveTo(ex, ey);
        triangle.lineTo(x3, y3);
        triangle.lineTo(x4, y4);
        triangle.close();
        mCanvas.drawPath(triangle, mPaint);
    }

    // Calculate
    public double[] rotateVec(int px, int py, double ang, boolean isChLen, double newLen) {
        double mathstr[] = new double[2];
        // 矢量旋转函数，参数含义分别是x分量、y分量、旋转角、是否改变长度、新长度
        double vx = px * Math.cos(ang) - py * Math.sin(ang);
        double vy = px * Math.sin(ang) + py * Math.cos(ang);
        if (isChLen) {
            double d = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
            vx = vx / d * newLen;
            vy = vy / d * newLen;
            mathstr[0] = vx;
            mathstr[1] = vy;
        }
        return mathstr;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            float minX = 0;
            float minY = 0;
            float maxX = 0;
            float maxY = 0;
            switch (mAnnotation.getShape()) {
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_ARROW:
                minX = 0;
                minY = 0;
                maxX = getLeft() + getWidth() - mAnnotation.getRadius();
                maxY = getTop() + getHeight() - mAnnotation.getRadius();
                break;
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_SQUARES:
                minX = getLeft() + mAnnotation.getRadius() / 2;
                minY = getTop() + mAnnotation.getRadius() / 2;
                maxX = getLeft() + getWidth() - mAnnotation.getRadius() / 2;
                maxY = getTop() + getHeight() - mAnnotation.getRadius() / 2;
                break;
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_CIRCLE:
                minX = 0;
                minY = 0;
                maxX = getLeft() + getWidth() - mAnnotation.getRadius();
                maxY = getTop() + getHeight() - mAnnotation.getRadius();
            case Annotation.KEY_SHAPE_TRIANGLE:
                minX = getLeft() + mAnnotation.getRadius();
                minY = getTop() + mAnnotation.getRadius();
                maxX = getLeft() + getWidth() - mAnnotation.getRadius();
                maxY = getTop() + getHeight() - mAnnotation.getRadius();
                break;
            }
            if (x > minX && x < maxX && y > minY && y < maxY) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mAnnotation.setX(x);
                    mAnnotation.setY(y);
                    postInvalidate();
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mAnnotation.setX(x);
                    mAnnotation.setY(y);
                    postInvalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void startAnnotate(String pathName) {
        mAnnotation = new Annotation();
        mAnnotation.setMaxRadius(getWidth() / 2);
        mAnnotation.setColor(Color.RED);
        mAnnotation.setX(getWidth() / 2);
        mAnnotation.setY(getHeight() / 2);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(KEY_STROKE_WIDTH);
        annotations.add(mAnnotation);

        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void stopAnnotate() {
        if (annotations.isEmpty()) {
            mPaint = null;
            mAnnotation = null;
        } else {
            annotations.remove(annotations.size() - 1);
            if (annotations.isEmpty()) {
                mAnnotation = null;
                mPaint = null;
            } else {
                mAnnotation = annotations.get(annotations.size() - 1);
                mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mPaint.setColor(mAnnotation.getColor());
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(KEY_STROKE_WIDTH);
            }
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void plus() {
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            mAnnotation.plus();
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    public void sub() {
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            mAnnotation.sub();
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    public void rotateRight() {
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            if (mAnnotation.getDegree() >= 360) {
                mAnnotation.setDegree(0);
            } else {
                mAnnotation.setDegree(mAnnotation.getDegree() + 90);
            }
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    public void rotateLeft() {
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            if (mAnnotation.getDegree() <= 0) {
                mAnnotation.setDegree(270);
            } else {
                mAnnotation.setDegree(mAnnotation.getDegree() - 90);
            }
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    public void changeColor(int color) {
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            mAnnotation.setColor(color);
            mPaint.setColor(color);
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Change the shape
     * 
     * @param id
     */
    public void changeShape(int id) {
        if (mAnnotation != null) {
            mAnnotation.setShape(id);
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draw line
     * 
     * @param fromX
     *            start point x
     * @param fromY
     *            start point y
     * @param toX
     *            end point x
     * @param toY
     *            end point y
     */
    public void drawLine(float fromX, float fromY, float toX, float toY) {
        Path linePath = new Path();
        linePath.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
        linePath.lineTo(toX, toY);
        linePath.close();
        mCanvas.drawPath(linePath, mPaint);
        invalidate();
    }

    public List<Annotation> getAnnotations() {
        return annotations;
    }

    private void rotatePath(Path path, float degree) {
        Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
        RectF bounds = new RectF();
        path.computeBounds(bounds, true);
        mMatrix.postRotate(degree, (bounds.right + bounds.left) / 2, (bounds.bottom + bounds.top) / 2);
        path.transform(mMatrix);
    }
}
```

2. In your activity, create the AnnotationView and assign your image to it, then append this view to your root view.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AnnotationView mPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);    
    AnnotationView mAnnotationView = new AnnotationView(this);                  
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = CBitmapUtil.decode(mPictureFile); // Get your image as a bitmap
        mAnnotationView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mPreview.addView(mAnnotationView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Photo cannot be saved, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```