# Using method -canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint)

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-canvas

I need to draw a bitmap inside of a specified rectangle. Why is it not drawn?

```
canvas.drawBitmap(MyBitmap, null, rectangle, null)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**EDIT**

---

The original answer is incorrect.
You can use the sourceRect to specify a part of a Bitmap to draw.
It may be null, in which case the whole image will be used.

As per the fryer comment he was drawing beneath something, I'll add a note on that.

`drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRect, paint)`
 does not handle Z `ordering (depth)` and the order of calling draw on object matters.

If you have 3 shapes to be drawn, square, triangle and circle. If you want the square to be on top then it must be drawn last.

---

You're not specified any source, so its not drawn anything.

Example:

You have a Bitmap 100x100 pixels. You want to draw the whole Bitmap.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(MyBitmap, new Rect(0,0,100,100), rectangle, null);
```

You want to draw only the left half of the bitmap.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(MyBitmap, new Rect(0,0,50,100), rectangle, null);
```

You need to specify the source rect, the source rect can be a rectangle anywhere from 0,0 to the width,height of the bitmap.

Comment: src - May be null. The subset of the bitmap to be drawn 
----dst  -The rectangle that the bitmap will be scaled/translated to fit into -------- I tried what you said but its still not showing up for some reason....

Comment: Wait it started working, I was drawing the bitmaps underneath the rectangles on the screen. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add how were you drawing the bitmap underneath the rectangles, I am having the same problem and am stuck on it for hours!

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell me what is `rectangle` used for?

Comment: what does mean by rectangle here ?

Comment: rectangle is the destination rectangle of where you want to draw your image.

Answer (score 32):

The main item to remember when defining the Rect is:

- **left < right** and ***top < bottom***

The rect is in screen coordinates (positive Y downward) ...

I find it helpful to think of the Rect arguments

```
(left, top, right, bottom)
```

as

```
(X, Y, X + Width, Y + Height)
```

where X,Y is the top left corner of the sprite image.

NOTE: If want to center the image on a particular location, remember to offset those values by half the sprite width & height. For example:

```
int halfWidth = Width/2;
int halfHeight = Height/2
Rect dstRectForRender = new Rect( X - halfWidth, Y - halfHeight, X + halfWidth, Y + halfHeight );
canvas.drawBitmap ( someBitmap, null, dstRectForRender, null );
```

This uses the whole original image (since src rect is null) and scales it to fit the size and position from dstRectForRender ... and using the default Paint.

Comment: Rly odd thx without this answer it is imposible to figure it out :)

Comment: How to align this icon to middile of the canvas??

Comment: This helped me : left < right and top < bottom. Very Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me!

```
Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,100,100);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rectangle, null);
```