# NullPointerException trying to draw bitmap

Tags: android

I have a NullPointerException being thrown in my code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(icon, null, rect, null);
```

I have a Log statement right above there to make sure the canvas is not null. I'm guessing the 2nd Rect being null is the problem? I thought it was ok to leave it as null.

Here is the logCat output:

```
07-22 21:34:16.807: E/AndroidRuntime(19340): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3384
07-22 21:34:16.807: E/AndroidRuntime(19340): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 21:34:16.807: E/AndroidRuntime(19340):    at
android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:118)
07-22 21:34:16.807: E/AndroidRuntime(19340):    at   
com.live.LedgeView$DrawLedgeThread.run(LedgeView.java:88)
```

Comment: `icon` is `null`? Or `rect` is `null`?

Comment: No, I have that logged too

Comment: Yes, I have log statements for all 3 variables

Comment: Are you calling `canvas.drawBitmap()` from inside onDraw()? Can you post the Logcat?

Comment: No, I actually have onDraw() kicking of a thread, to which I pass the canvas. the thread is calling canvas.drawBitmap(). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Would depend. Post your logcat output. That would help.

Comment: Check these out: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21364, http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24830

Comment: Yes, seems like a not fixed bug. You need to pass a not null source.

Comment: why you put canvas.drawBitmap() in thread? it has to be called in UI thread

Comment: and if you use multi-thread to operate your bitmap.be careful of bitmap recycling

Comment: Right, it will throw a RuntimeException in that case. As already said, do all the UI updates in the UIThread, thst's the safest way and the way recommended in the API Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Please make sure the "icon" bitmap is not null and "rect" also,

```
 Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.icon);
```

Please refer these link. It may help you out.
[Click Here to see sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691985/using-method-canvas-drawbitmapbitmap-src-dst-paint)

[Click here to see sample 2](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=19639)

Answer (score 0):

From the Android source code:

```
public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint) {
    if (dst == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    throwIfRecycled(bitmap);
    native_drawBitmap(mNativeCanvas, bitmap.ni(), src, dst,
                      aint != null ? paint.mNativePaint : 0,
                      mScreenDensity, bitmap.mDensity);
}
```

So...are you sure `dst` is not null?

In any case post the logcat stack trace.

Edit: In response to one of your comments, never update UI components from outside the UI Thread. Use `AsyncTask` if you need to fetch the `Bitmap` asynchronously.

```
new AsyncTask(Void,Void,Bitmap){

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids){
        //fetch Bitmap
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
        //fetch Bitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,...);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm initializing it right above: rect = new Rect(blx, bly, trx, trx);

Comment: the only ui component being updated is the canvas itself, and since that is done via a thread started in onDraw(), shouldnt that be ok?

Answer (score 0):

usually, I do this way. I decode bitmap by a thread, and put it into a queue. synchronize the queue with UI thread. the UI thread gets bitmap from the queue, and draw it. all UI stuff should be done in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Null Pointer Ex. in 
android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap

I read that you must do the "drawBitmap" inside of your onDraw method (in your view class).

for me, i used the invalidate() method for trigger onDraw. Before calling invalidate() i set some parameters to my object (of view class), so, when onDraw is called, it uses the parameters I put.

Hope it works :)

Leonardo.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint) {
    if (dst == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    throwIfRecycled(bitmap);
    native_drawBitmap(mNativeCanvas, bitmap.ni(), src, dst,
            aint != null ? paint.mNativePaint : 0, mScreenDensity,
            bitmap.mDensity);
}
```

I have fixed this issue by checking dst for null before sending to that method. If dst is null i have used local variable that i have stored every time on the method "onBoundsChange". This resolve my issue.