# how to print the content of an android activity on paper using a printer

Tags: android, printing, screenshot, android-print-framework

I have an activity which contains a photo (taken by the camera using start activity for result) and some text in editboxes. I want to print the content of this complete activity on paper. Saw the google docs which say that i will need to convert the content into a pdf document before i print it. It also has the example how to convert text into pdf doc but what about the image ?  The print can be even the screen shot of the activity (in larger size than the phone screen though)

Can anyone please guide me to any tutorial example of such a work or a sample code to understand how to do it... thanks for sharing knowledge...!

Comment: did you manage to solve this. Even i am looking similar one.

Comment: Nope, the requirement changed. client said only to print the text. We used printmarvel bluetooth printers for printing the text. It has its own app for that purpose and all you need to just pass the text to be printed as the argument to printers app. Only problem is that this gives receipts kind of prints. However was suitable for our requirements.

Comment: @ Pawan Rawat,thaks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you saw this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html).
In it there is this method.

```
private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page) {
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    // units are in points (1/72 of an inch)
    int titleBaseLine = 72;
    int leftMargin = 54;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(36);
    canvas.drawText("Test Title", leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);

    paint.setTextSize(11);
    canvas.drawText("Test paragraph", leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 25,          paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 172, 172, paint);
}
```

To draw a picture use the `Canvas`.[`drawBitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint)) method.
First get a bitmap from an `ImageView`.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Then draw it:

```
canvas.drawBitmap ( bitmap, null, new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100), null );
```

Also, look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691985/using-method-canvas-drawbitmapbitmap-src-dst-paint).