# How to start fresh on canvas ?

Tags: android, canvas

In my app I am drawing many things on canvas.
Before I draw a new figure I want to remove all the previous drawings and start afresh.

In other words I want to perform a NEW-operation as we do it in MS-Paint with a fresh canvas, nothing drawn on it.

How can I achieve such funstionality ?
Please help.

Comment: You could just remove the bitmaps that are currently on the screen by making the bitmaps null, or making a new canvas and put no draw commands after it. I guess it depends on how your code is as well, because I have set up a method to clear images from the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to draw a desired starting color onto your entire canvas.
If you want to to be clear, as origionally.

```
myCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

Or if you want a white background like MSPaint

```
myCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); // Will accept any color.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the Canvas, you can do this:

```
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                    ...
                    canvas.drawBitmap(fundo, 0, 0, null);
                    ...
```

In this case, I am drawing the back scene again, but you can "clear" the canvas too using

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729377/android-canvas-how-do-i-clear-delete-contents-of-a-canvas-bitmaps-livin)