# on progress change i want to draw rectangle

Tags: java, android

Hy everyone,

if seekbar or radiobutton change i want to draw rectengle on imageview, but rectengle isnt only one but on imageview is a lot of rectengles,(smaller), but i dont know why.

If i change valeu of seekbar i want the ractangle draw

```
private void draw() {

imageview.draw(canvas);
canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 350, 350,mPaint);
imageview.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);

}
```

In first picture we can see at the moment state of drawing, but in second i want it only one rectengle
[image: slika]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Android, canvas: How do I clear (delete contents of) a canvas (= bitmaps), living in a surfaceView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729377/android-canvas-how-do-i-clear-delete-contents-of-a-canvas-bitmaps-livin)

you can call `canvas.drawColor(Color.Black)` to redraw all black.
So finally you will have.

```
private void draw() {

    imageview.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.Black);
    canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 350, 350,mPaint);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);

}
```