# Getting default color black to clear the paint. How to change a color?

Tags: android, colors, android-canvas, paint

I used this code to clear the paint:

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Explain, and put some part of code where you want to change

Comment: i'm using to clear the canvas "paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));" dis stmt. but it shows default colour black when clear the paint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729377/android-canvas-how-do-i-clear-delete-contents-of-a-canvas-bitmaps-livin

Answer (score 2):

Try that, drawView is the canvas name

```
drawView.clearPoints();
```

Add method;

```
public void clearPoints() {
    points.clear();
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your own color on canvas like this :

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```