# Android Canvas Clear with transparency

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am trying to "erase" from a canvas.  Just as a VERY simple test of clearing a canvas, I have implemented the following:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(140, 0, 0, 0));
    canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
}
```

`Color.argb(140, 0, 0, 0)` sets the view this view is drawn over to be dimmed.  `drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR)` makes the screen completely black, rather than removing the dimming applied earlier.  [The idea was taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729377/android-canvas-how-do-i-clear-delete-contents-of-a-canvas-bitmaps-livin)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);` making the screen completely black is the intended functionality, so it's not really clear what you are asking/trying to accomplish - because you are accomplishing it.  If what you are trying to do is just temporarily dim a view/shade a bitmap, then remove the dimming effect, that's not really "clearing" the canvas.

Comment: Well, what I was trying to accomplish was to set a custom view to overlay an activity, that custom view would fill the screen with a low-alpha black to provide a dimming pattern, and then I would want a circle somewhere on the screen that did NOT have the dimming pattern

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the following.

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,Mode.CLEAR);
```

Comment: That's already what I have in my code, since Color.TRANSPARENT is a constant for 0.  I have already found a solution though, thank you.

Comment: This single line solution is much better than whatever double Canvas/Bitmap nonsense is going on in the accepted answer.

Comment: As Michael Herbig says this should be the answer. Using a Bitmap will use twice as much memory and cause another level of buffering!

Comment: As stated in my original comment, I already had this exact line in my original code (see OP), however it did not work for me at the time, 3 years later it seems this has helped more people than my own own, so I will mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Doing this, my Canvas becomes totally black

Comment: How to make it transparent?

Answer (score 13):

The solution was to create a secondary canvas and bitmap to draw on.  My Custom View's onSizeChanged() method looked like

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    temp = new Canvas(bitmap);
}
```

and the onDrawMethod looks like

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    temp.drawColor(Color.argb(80, 0, 0, 0));
    temp.drawCircle(centerPosX, centerPosY, 200, transparentPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

where transparentPaint is declared in the onstructor as

```
transparentPaint = new Paint();
transparentPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
transparentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
transparentPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: Great answer! You saved me! Thank You a lot! :))

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the whole view to transparent, otherwise, the transparent color will be black.

At the constructor of the view that you are overwriting set the alpha to zero.

```
setAlpha(0); // this is the secret.
```

Then, at you onDraw() method, you can clear the view:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // ...
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,Mode.CLEAR);
    // do you painting here
}
```