# What are best practices for Android heavy rendering

Tags: android, rx-java, ondraw, heavy-computation

## Questions

- What are the best practices for heavy rendering in Android views?
- Is the suggested approach is pointing in the right direction?
- What are the alternatives?

## Description

My Android app scrolls through `heavy rendered content`. Rendering of one screen can take up to 500 ms. The final image should be displayed to the user.

`Heavy rendering` can be triggered multiple times per second (up to 20 times), simply via finger dragging.

In general only the last call matters. The intermediate non-processed calls can be dropped. If the intermediate call was processed though, it makes sense to display result to the user while the next/last call is rendering.

Obviously if you place `heavy rendering` into the main thread, the UI will be frozen and user experience will suffer.

## Current implementation

### Idea

Heavy rendering together with "last call matters" requirement let you think about using a separate thread and [`RxJava Flowable`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html).

The idea is to have two bitmaps:

- `intermediate bitmap` - use it in a thread, let `heavy rendering` take as much time as it needs to draw the picture
- `final bitmap` - use it to store the final picture and display to the user if the app is calling onDraw function

Steps:

1. After processing is triggered, the call is buffered and only the last available processed
2. The rendering is performed into the `intermediate bitmap` (this is a long process)
3. After rendering is finished, `intermediate bitmap` is transferred to the `final bitmap` (this should be quick)
4. `final bitmap` is drawn on the screen anytime app wants to refresh the screen (this should also be quick). Steps 3 and 4 should `synchronized` to prevent flickering.

### Schema

Schematic it looks like that:

```
   intermediate   -->   final   -->   screen
      bitmap            bitmap        bitmap 

      [long]           [quick]       [quick]

(Rendering thread)      ?   (--- Main thread ---)
|---------- sync1? ----------|
                       |------- sync2 ------|
```

### Code

Technically it can be done like that (also schematic, some details are omitted):

```java
// trigger initialization
void init() {
    mCanvasIntermediate = new Canvas(mBitmapIntermediate);
    mCanvasFinal = new Canvas(mBitmapFinal);

    rendering = PublishSubject.create();
    rendering
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        .onBackpressureLatest()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 1)
        .flatMapSingle(canvas -> Single.create(emitter -> {
            canvas.drawBitmap(...);
            emitter.onSuccess(result);
        }))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // <-- comment to put invalidate to the thread
        .subscribe(result -> {
            mCanvasIntermediate.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            mCanvasFinal.drawBitmap(mBitmapIntermediate, ...);
            invalidate();
        });
}

// triggering
void triggerRendering() {
    rendering.onNext(mCanvasIntermediate);
}

// view ondraw
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapFinal, ...);
}
```

### Problem

In general it works, but not perfect:

- if both rendering and output intermediate->final are placed to the main thread, the screen is freezing on rendering,
- if only output intermediate->final is placed to the main thread, the screen is flickering,
- if both rendering and output intermediate->final are placed to the calculation thread only a part of the screen is displayed during the rendering process.

## Update:

This comment helped me a lot:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57610119/10475643

It appeared, that this line caused the whole skirmish:

```
mCanvasIntermediate.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

Because `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` does not work well with [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel). This caused flickering and partial screen output. At the end I placed the both `drawBitmap`s to the thread. As long as I removed `drawColor` or turned off hardware acceleration, flickering disappeared.