# Jetpack Compose watermark or write on Bitmap with androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

With `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas`, default Canvas for Jetpack Compose, or **Spacer with Modifier.drawBehind{}** under the hood

```
@Composable
fun Canvas(modifier: Modifier, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) =
    Spacer(modifier.drawBehind(onDraw
```

correctly refreshes drawing on Canvas when mutableState `Offset` changes

```
var offset by remember {
    mutableStateOf(Offset(bitmapWidth / 2f, bitmapHeight / 2f))
}  

Canvas(modifier = canvasModifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val canvasWidth = size.width.roundToInt()
        val canvasHeight = size.height.roundToInt()
    
        drawImage(
            image = dstBitmap,
            srcSize = IntSize(dstBitmap.width, dstBitmap.height),
            dstSize = IntSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
        )
    
        drawCircle(
            center = offset,
            color = Color.Red,
            radius = canvasHeight.coerceAtMost(canvasWidth) / 8f,
        )
    }
```

With `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas`, Canvas that takes an ImageBitmap as argument and draws to as in description of it

> Create a new Canvas instance that targets its drawing commands to the
> provided ImageBitmap

I add full implementation to test this out easily and much appreciated if you come up with a solution.

```
@Composable
fun NativeCanvasSample2(imageBitmap: ImageBitmap, modifier: Modifier) {
    
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier) {

        val imageWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        val imageHeight = constraints.maxHeight

        val bitmapWidth = imageBitmap.width
        val bitmapHeight = imageBitmap.height

        var offset by remember {
            mutableStateOf(Offset(bitmapWidth / 2f, bitmapHeight / 2f))
        }


        val canvasModifier = Modifier.pointerMotionEvents(
            Unit,
            onDown = {
                val position = it.position
                val offsetX = position.x * bitmapWidth / imageWidth
                val offsetY = position.y * bitmapHeight / imageHeight
                offset = Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
                it.consumeDownChange()
            },
            onMove = {
                val position = it.position
                val offsetX = position.x * bitmapWidth / imageWidth
                val offsetY = position.y * bitmapHeight / imageHeight
                offset = Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
                it.consumePositionChange()
            },
            delayAfterDownInMillis = 20
        )

        val canvas: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas = Canvas(imageBitmap)
        

        val paint1 = remember {
            Paint().apply {
                color = Color.Red
            }
        }
        canvas.apply {
            val nativeCanvas = this.nativeCanvas
            val canvasWidth = nativeCanvas.width.toFloat()
            val canvasHeight = nativeCanvas.height.toFloat()

            drawCircle(
                center = offset,
                radius = canvasHeight.coerceAtMost(canvasWidth) / 8,
                paint = paint1
            )
        }


        Image(
            modifier = canvasModifier,
            bitmap = imageBitmap,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )

        Text(
            "Offset: $offset",
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )
    }
}
```

First issue it never refreshes **Canvas** without `Text` or something else reading `Offset`.

Second issue is as in the image below. It doesn't clear previous drawing on Image, i tried every possible solution in [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729377/android-canvas-how-do-i-clear-delete-contents-of-a-canvas-bitmaps-livin) but none of them worked.

[image]

I tried drawing image with BlendMode, drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,Mode.Multiply) with native canvas and many combinations still not able to have the same result with Jetpack Compose Canvas.

```
    val erasePaint = remember {
        Paint().apply {
            color = Color.Transparent
            blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
        }
    }

with(canvas.nativeCanvas) {
    val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

    drawImage(imageBitmap, topLeftOffset = Offset.Zero, erasePaint)
    drawCircle(
        center = offset,
        radius = canvasHeight.coerceAtMost(canvasWidth) / 8,
        paint = paint1
    )
    
    restoreToCount(checkPoint)
}
```

I need to use `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas` as you can see operations on Canvas are reflected to Bitmap and using this i'm planning to create foundation for cropping Bitmap

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally, after 6 months, figured out how it can be done and how you can modify Bitmap instance using `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas`

First create an empty mutable bitmap with same dimensions of original bitmap. This is what we will draw on. The trick here is not sending a real bitmap but an empty bitmap

```
val bitmapWidth = imageBitmap.width
val bitmapHeight = imageBitmap.height

val bmp: Bitmap = remember {
    Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
}
```

Then since we draw nothing at the base we can use `drawColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)`

to clear on each draw then draw image and apply any blend mode using Paint

```
val paint = remember {
    Paint()
}

val erasePaint = remember {
    Paint().apply {
        color = Color.Red
        blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
    }
}

canvas.apply {
    val nativeCanvas = this.nativeCanvas
    val canvasWidth = nativeCanvas.width.toFloat()
    val canvasHeight = nativeCanvas.height.toFloat()

    with(canvas.nativeCanvas) {
       drawColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

        drawCircle(
            center = offset,
            radius = 400f,
            paint = paint
        )

        drawImageRect(
            image = imageBitmap,
            dstSize = IntSize(canvasWidth.toInt(), canvasHeight.toInt()),
            paint = erasePaint
        )
    }
}
```

Finally draw bitmap we used in Canvas to Image Composable using

```
Image(
    modifier = canvasModifier.border(2.dp, Color.Green),
    bitmap = bmp.asImageBitmap(),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
)
```

or you can save this modified ImageBitmap with watermark or any overlay you draw into canvas

Full implementation

```
@Composable
fun NativeCanvasSample2(imageBitmap: ImageBitmap, modifier: Modifier) {

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier) {

        val imageWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        val imageHeight = constraints.maxHeight

        val bitmapWidth = imageBitmap.width
        val bitmapHeight = imageBitmap.height

        var offset by remember {
            mutableStateOf(Offset(bitmapWidth / 2f, bitmapHeight / 2f))
        }

        val bmp: Bitmap = remember {
            Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        }

        val canvas: Canvas = remember {
            Canvas(bmp.asImageBitmap())
        }

        val paint = remember {
            Paint()
        }

        val erasePaint = remember {
            Paint().apply {
                color = Color.Red
                blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
            }
        }

        canvas.apply {
            val nativeCanvas = this.nativeCanvas
            val canvasWidth = nativeCanvas.width.toFloat()
            val canvasHeight = nativeCanvas.height.toFloat()

            with(canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                drawColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

                drawCircle(
                    center = offset,
                    radius = 400f,
                    paint = paint
                )

                drawImageRect(
                    image = imageBitmap,
                    dstSize = IntSize(canvasWidth.toInt(), canvasHeight.toInt()),
                    paint = erasePaint
                )
            }
        }
        
        val canvasModifier = Modifier.pointerMotionEvents(
            Unit,
            onDown = {
                val position = it.position
                val offsetX = position.x * bitmapWidth / imageWidth
                val offsetY = position.y * bitmapHeight / imageHeight
                offset = Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
                it.consume()
            },
            onMove = {
                val position = it.position
                val offsetX = position.x * bitmapWidth / imageWidth
                val offsetY = position.y * bitmapHeight / imageHeight
                offset = Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
                it.consume()
            },
            delayAfterDownInMillis = 20
        )

        Image(
            modifier = canvasModifier.border(2.dp, Color.Green),
            bitmap = bmp.asImageBitmap(),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )
    }
}
```

Result

[image]